# add() method on entrySet() in Map<>

Tags: java, dictionary, entryset

While iterating `Map<>` using for loop

```
for(Map.Entry<K,V> mapEntry : myMap.entrySet()){
    // something
}
```

I found `entrySet()` method returns a set of `Entry<K,V>`

so it has `add(Entry<K,V> e)` method

then I created a class which implements `Map.Entry<K,V>` and tried inserting the object like below

```
    public final class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {

    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        V old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
    }

}


Entry<String, String> entry = new MyEntry<String, String>("Hello", "hello");
myMap.entrySet().add(entry); //line 32
```

there is no compilation error,
but it throws a runtime error

```
    Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:262)
    at com.seeth.AboutEntrySetThings.main(AboutEntrySetThings.java:32)
```

Comment: What type is myMap?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I used HashMap here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JavaDoc on `entrySet()` method:

> The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `add()` method on the `entrySet()` of `HashMap` and **there is no such implementation in that class, only in its superclasses**.

From `HashMap` source code:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}

final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
// there is no add() override
}
```

Because `add()` method is not overriden (neither in `HashMap.EntrySet`, nor in `AbstractSet`), a method from `AbstractCollection` will be used, which has the following definition:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

---

Also, looking on the [`entrySet()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--):

> (...) The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. **It does not support the add or addAll operations.**

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for that method
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#add(E)
says

> This implementation always throws an UnsupportedOperationException.

Then subclasses override it and `public void add(int size, E element);`
The subclass `EntrySet` in `HashMap` does not override it.

Answer (score 0):

Method java.util.HashMap.entrySet() returns a class java.util.HashMap.EntrySet, which itself does not implement method Set.add().
To add an object to the collection, you must use method myMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()).

Method entrySet() is used only for reading data, and not for modification.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect; `entrySet()` supports removal